# RETURN statements in scalar valued functions must include an argument

Tags: sql-server, function

Didn't manage to find an aswer for the problem. Therefore, decided to share it here. Hope it will help anybody and professionals will share more efficient solution

I created a function in MSSQL that takes a parameter and try to find corresponding record in a mapping table. The extraction of mapping record was implemented using 'With clause':

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMappedValue]
(
    @field nvarchar(50) = null
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS 
BEGIN
    ;WITH active_mappings AS 
        (SELECT map_key, map_value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY map_key ORDER BY updated DESC) AS n
                FROM MappingTable WHERE tag = 'Active')

    RETURN SELECT TOP 1 map_value FROM active_mappings 
           WHERE n=1 AND map_key = @field
END
GO
```

But for a strange reason: 'RETURN statements in scalar valued functions must include an argument' error occurs

Comment: `select top 1` could still produce 0 records. `Return` doesn't like that.

Comment: Why not convert this into an inline table valued function instead? It can handle NULL, will be better for performance and it more flexible to use.

Comment: Sean, could you please create an example with your solution? Unfortunately, I am not a professional in mssql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how this same function would look as an inline table valued function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMappedValue]
(
    @field nvarchar(50) = null
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
    WITH active_mappings AS 
    (
        SELECT map_value
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY map_key ORDER BY updated DESC) AS n
        FROM MappingTable 
        WHERE tag = 'Active'
            AND map_key = @field
    )

    SELECT TOP 1 map_value 
    FROM active_mappings 
    WHERE n = 1 
    --ORDER BY ??? You have top 1 but no order by. As such you don't know which row will be returned
GO
```

**---EDIT---**

Since you said there can only be a single value returned from MappingTable you could greatly simplify this. The entire body of your function could be this simple.

```
select map_value
from MappingTable mt
where tag = 'Active'
    and map_key = @field
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Sean - active_mappings table contains unique values in map_key column and as a result can't have more than 1 value

Comment: In that case the top 1 is irrelevant, just remove it.

Answer (score 4):

In order to solve the problem I had to declare a variable and assign result of select into the variable and only afterwards return it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMappedValue]
(
    @field nvarchar(50) = null
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS 
BEGIN
    Declare @result nvarchar(50)
    ;WITH active_mappings AS 
        (SELECT map_key, map_value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY map_key ORDER BY updated DESC) AS n
                FROM MappingTable WHERE tag = 'Active')

    SELECT @Result = (SELECT TOP 1 map_value FROM active_mappings 
           WHERE n=1 AND map_key = @field)

     RETURN @Result
END
GO
```