# Return variable using OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, openquery

I am trying to make a simple function that reads a table from an ORACLE database and returns a sequence number. I would either like to return it directly or store the value inside of @cwpSeq and return that to the calling program.

Right now I am getting error:

> RETURN statements in scalar valued functions must include an argument.

Can anyone assist me.

```
create  function dbo.get_cwpSeq_from_oracle(@COIL nvarchar(100) )
returns int as

begin

    DECLARE @cwpSeq int, @SQL nvarchar(1000);
    set @SQL = N'select * from openquery(DEV, 'select cwp_seq from apps.custom_wip_pieces where lot_number = ''' + @COIL + '')';
    
    return execute sp_executesql @SQL;
end;
```

Comment: selct * never can return an integer, so please explain what exactly you want to returm

Comment: You can't use dynamicSql in a function, you should consider using a procedure with an output parameter.

Comment: Hope this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993147/return-statements-in-scalar-valued-functions-must-include-an-argument/48993148 or maybe this: https://www.exacthelp.com/2012/03/return-statements-in-scalar-valued.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, in this case you should use a procedure with an output parameter instead of a function. If you want to fully execute the query on the Oracle linked server side and return some value after that, I would suggest using dynamic as follows:

```
Create Or Alter Procedure dbo.get_cwpSeq
    @COIL nvarchar(100),
    @cwp_seq Int Output
As

Declare @QueryText nVarChar(max)

Select @QueryText = 'Select @cwp_seq=cwp_seq 
                     From Openquery(DEV, 
                     ''Select cwp_seq 
                       From apps.custom_wip_pieces 
                       Where lot_number= ''''' + @COIL + ''''''') As Ora'; 
Execute sp_executesql @QueryText, N'@COIL nvarchar(100), @cwp_seq Int Output', @COIL = @COIL, @cwp_seq = @cwp_seq Output
```

As far as I understand in your case:
Linked server is "DEV", Owner of the table is "apps".

Comment: Anton thank you for the reply. I just have a quick clarifying question.  
So "DEV" is our generic name for our ORACLE DB that we want to connect to. For example if I run this command in sql developer I get returned 'A' 

select * from openquery(DEV, 'select ''A'' from dual ');

We use a schema called WSCTS so would the call still be "...DEV.WSCTS.dbo.sp_executesql..."

Comment: @esjones I'm sorry, it's my fault. I posted an edited version of the procedure for Oracle Linked Server.

Comment: that did the trick! Thank you!!

Comment: @esjones You are welcome!